# What does AVCaptureDevice's low light boost do?

Tags: ios, iso, avcapturedevice, ios-camera

AVCaptureDevice has a property [isLowLightBoostSupported](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624595-islowlightboostsupported). What does it do? Just multiply each pixel value with a constant? I could do that myself, in theory.

Or does it do anything at the hardware level, which I can't do myself?